# UNITY BUILD AUTOMATION: An app icon measuring 1024 by 1024 pixels in PNG format must be included in the Asset Catalog of apps

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, app-store, devops, unity-cloud-build

I'm building a game in unity for ios. I've been using unity cloud build. I've made a previous app that was successfuly published to the app store. The icon is 1024x1024 just like the message says that it should be. There are no other errors with theapp so in that regards it is building sucessfuly. I have post-build.bash file that uploads the ipa to the app store. This is when I get the error.

[target config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WESDv.png)
[player config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGaEs.png)

post-build.bash

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Uploading IPA to Appstore Connect..."
#Path is "/BUILD_PATH/<ORG_ID>.<PROJECT_ID>.<BUILD_TARGET_ID>/.build/last/<BUILD_TARGET_ID>/build.ipa"
path="$WORKSPACE/.build/last/$TARGET_NAME/build.ipa"
if xcrun altool --upload-app -t ios -f $path -u $ITUNES_USERNAME -p $ITUNES_PASSWORD ; then
    echo "Upload IPA to Appstore Connect finished with success"
else
    echo "Upload IPA to Appstore Connect failed"
fi
```